# Is there a simple way to subset unique values and their associated datum?

Tags: r, unique, subset, data-manipulation

I have a large data set that contains ~300,000 rows and 60 columns. Currently if I want to subset the unique characteristics within my one variable I use the `unique()` function to create a `data.frame` list of all the unique values in that variable. I then match it to the master data frame to get the associated data from my master file.

This process however is a little cumbersome, so I was wondering if there is a faster way to do the same thing?  for example, is there a function that I could use to select for unique fields and the associated data that is connected to those values?

For example: I would like to make a new data frame the contains only unique SurveyID_Block ID and their associated island code and abundances.

```
 structure(list(SurveyID_Block = c("62003713_2", "62003087_2", 
"62003713_2", "62003713_2", "62003713_1", "62003713_2", "62003713_1", 
"62003713_2", "62003713_2", "62003087_1", "62003713_1", "62003713_1", 
"62003713_2", "62003713_2", "62003713_1", "62003087_1", "62003087_2", 
"62003713_2", "62003713_2", "62003713_2", "62003087_2", "62003713_2", 
"62003713_1", "62003713_1", "62003713_1", "62003713_1", "62003713_2", 
"62003713_1", "62003713_2", "62003087_1", "62003713_2", "62003087_1", 
"62003713_1", "62003087_2", "62003087_2", "62003713_2", "62003713_1", 
"62003087_1", "62003713_1", "62003713_1", "62003713_1", "62003087_2", 
"62003087_2", "62003713_2", "62003713_2", "62003713_2", "62003713_1", 
"62003087_1", "62003713_2", "62003087_2", "62003713_1", "62003713_1", 
"62003713_2", "62003713_1", "62003713_2", "62003087_2", "62003087_2", 
"62003087_1", "62003087_1", "62003713_1", "62003087_1", "62003087_1", 
"62003087_2", "62003087_2", "62003713_2", "62003713_1", "62003713_2", 
"62003713_2", "62003713_2", "62003713_1", "62003713_2", "62003087_1", 
"62003713_1", "62003713_1", "62003087_1", "62003087_1", "62003713_1", 
"62003087_2", "62003087_1", "62003087_2", "62003087_2", "62003087_1", 
"62003087_1", "62003087_1", "62003713_2", "62003087_2", "62003713_2", 
"62003087_2", "62003713_1", "62003713_1", "62003087_2", "62003087_1", 
"62003087_1", "62003087_1", "62003713_2", "62003713_2", "62003087_1", 
"62003713_1", "62003087_1", "62003087_2"), IslandCode = c(1391L, 
1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 
1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 
1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 
1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 
1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 
1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 
1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 
1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 
1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 
1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 
1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L, 1391L
), totalAbun = c(667L, 174L, 667L, 667L, 715L, 667L, 715L, 667L, 
667L, 1365L, 715L, 715L, 667L, 667L, 715L, 1365L, 174L, 667L, 
667L, 667L, 174L, 667L, 715L, 715L, 715L, 715L, 667L, 715L, 667L, 
1365L, 667L, 1365L, 715L, 174L, 174L, 667L, 715L, 1365L, 715L, 
715L, 715L, 174L, 174L, 667L, 667L, 667L, 715L, 1365L, 667L, 
174L, 715L, 715L, 667L, 715L, 667L, 174L, 174L, 1365L, 1365L, 
715L, 1365L, 1365L, 174L, 174L, 667L, 715L, 667L, 667L, 667L, 
715L, 667L, 1365L, 715L, 715L, 1365L, 1365L, 715L, 174L, 1365L, 
174L, 174L, 1365L, 1365L, 1365L, 667L, 174L, 667L, 174L, 715L, 
715L, 174L, 1365L, 1365L, 1365L, 667L, 667L, 1365L, 715L, 1365L, 
174L)), .Names = c("SurveyID_Block", "IslandCode", "totalAbun"
), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is expected output? if `SurveyID_Block` always has same other attributes, wouldn't `unique(df)` work? this gives me just 4 rows.

Comment: Hi Ananta. That does work! So my question is how does the unique function  know what column variable to select? for example why didn't it do this for IslandCode?

Comment: @pr1g11 Have you tried the `split` solution posted below or in the dupe link?

Comment: @pr1g11 it did not select the first variable, all your variables have 1:1 relationship, so it's just selecting unique row, not ubique on one variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` the dataset by 'SurveyID_Block' to create a `list` of `data.frame`s.  It would be better to keep the datasets in a `list` rather than creating individual data.frame objects in the global environment.

```
lst <- split(df1, df1$SurveyID_Block)
```

But, if we need to create individual datasets, it can be done with `list2env`

```
list2env(setNames(lst, paste0('dfN', seq_along(lst))),
          envir=.GlobalEnv)
```